# A function or VBA code to determine the last digit in a number

Tags: excel, vba

In Excel 2016 I have multiple rows containing numbers no greater than 3 characters listed in column A. I am trying assign a group number based on the right most character in each row that are in column A. Once the number is determined the result is placed in column B of the corresponding row.

Example:

```
If rightmost character of the number is: a 1 or 6 in cell A1, then in column B1 it's given a 1.
If A1 is a 2 or 7 then B1 is 2.
If A1 is a 3 or 8 then B1 is 3.
If A1 is a 4 or 9 then B1 is 4.
If A1 is a 0 or 5 then B1 is 5.
```

Any suggestions on how to perform with a function or VBA code are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Following your problem statment exactly: in `B1` you can enter the formula:

```
=IF(MOD(MOD(A1,10),5)=0,5,MOD(MOD(A1,10),5))
```

And copy it down as needed.

The part `MOD(A1,10)` pulls off the last digit. You seem to want the remainder of this mod 5 -- hence the outer `MOD` in `(MOD(MOD(A1,10),5)`. But -- if the mod is 0 you want to report it as 5 -- hence the overall `IF`

However -- an even quicker way is just:

```
=IF(MOD(A1,5)=0,5,MOD(A1,5))
```

Since literally pulling off the first digit is superfluous since 5 is a divisor of 10.

Finally, @chrisneilsen gave an elegant formula which is even shorter:

```
=MOD(A1-1,5)+1
```

For all remainders other than 0 , the `-1` inside the `MOD` and the `+1` outside cancel each other, but for multiples of 5 (remainder 0) the `-1` inside the `MOD` converts the number to one with a remainder of 4, with 4 + 1 = 5 the final answer.

Comment: A cleaner formula on the same idea: `=MOD(A1-1,5)+1`

Comment: Or if you just want the last digit, regardless of the set-up of modulo, you could use Right(A1,1) to pull off the last digit.

Comment: @chrisneilsen Good idea. I'll add that to the answer.